# How To Set Border Margin on a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using the WPF DataGrid and have it set to place a red border around any row that the user modifies.  It works well, however when the border appears all the cells inside that row get pushed over a pixel or two.  In other words a cell's left and right border no longer lines up with the one above or below it, so it looks weird.

Here's the code I'm using to get the red border to appear OnEdit (Note: IsDirty is a property on my bound object that's set when a value gets modified):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />                    
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

What can I add so that I can modify the red border margins so that it won't interfere with the cells' borders?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Tree looks something like this

- DataGridRow

  - Border

    - DataGridCellsPresenter

When you change the `BorderThickness` of the `Border` you could compensate this by adding negative `Margin.Left`  to the `DataGridCellsPresenter` at the same time. Not the prettiest solution but it works

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!--...-->
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way could be to apply border to each row rather than the dirty one but set the border to transparent and set the border to red for the row which is actually dirty

Something like

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDirty}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Good idea.  Unfortunately when the row isn't red, this places a gap in between the borders of all cells.  So left border is a line then a small empty space, and then a line for the border below it.  I tried making it black instead of transparent, but the border is way too thick so it looks crazy.  Thanks anyway though.